# How to check sessionStorage value with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress.io and I'm trying to check if item in sessionStorage is being set.

**How do I check if item in sessionStorage exists?**

---

I've tried it by calling: `cy.wrap(sessionStorage.getItem('someItem')).should('exist');` but it looks like the value is being set on initialization because at the first test it says it `expected null` and in another test it expects old sessionStorage value (from previous test).

```js
it('can set sessionItem', function() {
   cy.visit('/handlerUrl')
   // ... some code
   cy.get('[type=submit]').click()
   cy.url().should('include', '/anotherUrl')
   cy.wrap(sessionStorage.getItem('someItem')).should('exist');
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use

```
cy.window()
  .its("sessionStorage")
  .invoke("getItem", "token")
  .should("exist");
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I had to use `cy.window()` which can get the window object of the page that is currently active.

```js
cy.window().then(win=> {
  const someItem = win.sessionStorage.getItem('someItem')
  cy.wrap(someItem).should('exist') // or 'not.empty'
});
```

More information about `cy.window()` can be found in [cypress.io documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html#Syntax).

Comment: Its not working still someItem is null

Comment: Then its probably not Cypress problem because documentation still mention windows and in my case it still works.